# OnClientClick doesn't work on asp button

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a button and a linkButton on my page and I want only use the `OnClientClick` event on them so I wrote this :

```
myButton.Attributes.Add("OnClientClick", "document.getElementById('popUp').style.display='block';document.getElementById('mask').style.display='block'; return false;");
myLinkButton.Attributes.Add("OnClientClick", "document.getElementById('popUp').style.display='block';document.getElementById('mask').style.display='block';return false;");
```

It works on an other page but not here, the `OnClientClick` is ignore and I don't understand why.

When I replace `OnClientClick` by `OnClick` it works fine but the postback is fired and I don't want refresh my page.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Link button is server side control and it fires postback when you use OnClick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`OnCLientClick`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a property of a serverside `Button`, so don't use `Attributes.Add` but:

```
myButton.OnClientClick = "document.getElementById('popUp').style.display='block';document.getElementById('mask').style.display='block'; return false;"
myLinkButton.OnClientClick = "document.getElementById('popUp').style.display='block';document.getElementById('mask').style.display='block';return false;"
```

From MSDN:

> The script that you specify for this property is rendered in the
>   Button control's **OnClick** attribute **in addition to the control's
>   predefined client-side script**.

I assume that other properties cause this issues that can write into the `OnClick` attribute like [`UseSubmitBehavior`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.usesubmitbehavior%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Ok it works with this method. I just have a single question : What is the difference between the `OnClientClick` use on the code behind and the `OnClientClick` use on the HTML ?

Comment: @Shadam: `OnClientClick` is not a html attribute, it's a serverside property which is used on serverside during generation of the clientside HTML. So there is obviously some functionality on this property that is not executed if you "hide" it as html-attribute.

Answer (score 0):

When you're adding attributes to the Attributes collection, those are actually the HTML attributes, not server side - and there's no HTML attribute OnClientClick, just onclick.

And onclick should work the way you want, unless there's an error (which I suspect is the case) in the code before return false.

Answer (score 0):

Give your button an ID attribute like ID="myButton" and ClientIDMode="Static", so you can fire event click on client side with javascript or jquery.